# PDF generated by Latex doesn't open in 100% zoom

Tags: pdf, latex, zooming

I created a pdf in Latex. All is well, except that I want to have the generated pdf to open at  100% zoom level by default when opened in adobe pdf reader. Currently, it is being displayed at 57%. I have also noticed other instances of pdf generated by my other Latex code being displayed at zoom levels other than 100%.

Is this just an issue with viewer or does this deviation from 100% zoom has to do something with Latex code in itself. I mean, if you change the page borders or something (or that the document type is article and not book or something else); does that effect the default zoom?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I do not remember LaTeX defaults, but for sure you can control zoom level using the hyperref package if you are not already doing so. Direct link to manual: [here](http://mirror.switch.ch/ftp/mirror/tex/macros/latex/contrib/hyperref/doc/manual.html#TBL-7-40-1)

```
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{pdfstartview={XYZ null null 1.00}}
```

Please note I do not have Acrobat Reader installed on the machine I'm writing these, so don't hesitate to report if somethings wrong. Also, assuming compilation with pdflatex.

Comment: so: `\hypersetup[pdfstartview=FitW]`.

Comment: Yes, and of course \usepackage{hyperref}. I'm editing to insert sample ;) edit: not exactly FitW, though

Comment: @Benoit, Strangely, using FitW opens with the appropriate zoom and an error popup saying "FitW" is an unknown destination. But FitH opens at the _same_ zoom (fit-width) and no error. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/3451/41109

Comment: With some templates (and AR version 11) `\hypersetup{pdfstartview={XYZ null null 0.758}}` (or other zoom level settings?) ends up with full width mode. Same thing can be achieved with `\hypersetup{pdfstartview={XYZ null null null}}` without specifying the constant.

Answer (score 4):

Start your code in this way if you want to compile your text either with pdflatex or latex.
Adequate it to your needs.

```
\RequirePackage{ifpdf}
\ifpdf
  \documentclass[pdftex,letterpaper,12pt]{article}
  \usepackage{lmodern}
  %  \usepackage{textcomp}   
\else
 \documentclass[dvips,letterpaper,12pt]{article}
%  \usepackage[active]{srcltx}  % for dvi viewers supporting source code mapping
\fi
```

But you may want to set the default zoom size in your viewer preferences option.
Evince viewer allows to configure the buttons of the top bar, add the scaling buttons.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use the `\usepackage[pdflatex]{hyperref}` package, compile with `pdflatex` (or `rubber -d`) and use the hypersetup setting I put in a comment above.

Comment: Why don't you put your comment in the answer? It worked like a charm and would make a complete answer.

Comment: Adobe reader version 11 threw an error on the proposed `\hypersetup{pdfstartview=FitW}`. What works is `\hypersetup{pdfstartview={XYZ null null null}}`.